# How to use Type C receptacle to power the device

Tags: usb-c

I'm designing a device which I want to be powered from a phone or tab charger through a standard USB cable. The device doesn't have any MCU, so it cannot communicate via USB. In fact, it is a sort of LED lamp, so it contains constant current circuit which is designed to draw from 400 to 700 mA at 5V input. The question is, how should I organize CC1 and CC2 pins on the device? After some reading, I understand that they should be connected to GND through separate 5.1k resistors. Am I correct?
[image]
*EDIT:* J1 is a USB Type C receptacle. In reality C1 isn't polar but a 1206 SMD ceramic. I believe that the rest of the device schematic is totally unrelated to my question.

Comment: What is the device in the schematic?

Comment: @HandyHowie Probably the Type C connector..

Comment: The polarized capacitor may not like the incorrect polarity.

Comment: @Justme added comment to the OP

Comment: @HandyHowie this is SMT Type C receptacle

Comment: Yes, connect both CC pins to ground via resistors in order to activate the Vbus supply at 5V. See [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/574317/usb-c-and-5v-power-supply). Your device would be the right hand side with the Rd resistors fitted.

Comment: @Finbarr many thanks!!!