# Correct lead routing for USB micro-b (male) to USB A and USB type C (+ mini HDMI)

Tags: pcb-design, usb, raspberry-pi, usb-c

I am trying to put together a custom adapter PCB to plug into a Raspberry Pi Zero/Zero 2 W so I can avoid using multiple adapter cables. On the Pi end, it'll have male plugs for mini HDMI, micro USB (OTG), and micro USB (power). On the other, female plugs for full-sized HDMI (rated only for 720p or 1080p to start I believe), USB A for peripherals, and USB type C for power only:

[image]

TL;DR is that I'm trying to validate the circuit design in the attached image. The long version is below.

My questions are:

1. Assuming the USB A port will be used only for peripherals and *not* to back-feed power into the Pi, am I correct that host mode should be enabled on the micro USB plug by connecting ID/Sense with GND?
2. For the power-only micro USB plug, is host mode necessary? Or do I just route VBUS and GND from the relevant pins on the type-C port?
3. Since no data is being passed from the type-C port to the micro USB plug, are any resistors needed on the type-C port? I know they are often used to signal whether a type-C is in host mode or not, but I'm wondering if that's needed here.
4. Am I correct in that all GND pins from the type-C port can be connected to each other and then routed to the GND pin on the micro USB plug? And is the same valid for VBUS as well? I want to make sure the type-C port allows for reversible plugging (naturally).

Bonus: If I wanted to swap the USB A port for type-C and forego the power-only port entirely, what's the best way to route everything for that? (Pi side: micro USB male; OTG side: fully reversible USB type-C female)

Comment: If you want to get power through the USB-C port you'll need to use resistors. [See this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/574317/usb-c-and-5v-power-supply)