# Detect voltage on a USBC PD charger?

Tags: usb-c

I wish to detect when a USB C PD charger is turned on (i.e. provides power):

```
CHARGER ---> (DETECTOR)
         |
          -> Notebook
```

So I wish to keep it as simple as possible. Charger needs to charge a notebook, so full PD negotiation is needed, as notebook needs 20V3A.

My goal is to have *sensor* which can detect that charger is connected into mains.

The sensor will provide this information to a microcontroller.

I thought on current sensors, but I don't wish to have that sophisticated information: I only want to know if the charger is *on* or *off*.

I also thought on voltage detection on CC1 and CC2 pins (CC and VCONN), which I kindof like, however, as the C cable is reversible, I either need to build or use 2 ADCs, or I must interconnect CC1 and CC2 (with protection).

(How) can I trust on these CC1 and CC2 pins to detect voltage on the charger's output?

Comment: 2 blocking diodes and a adc pin plus a ground connection seems like all you need.

Comment: USB-C won't provide power unless it's activated, so are you trying to detect whether is able to deliver power or whether it actually IS delivering power?

Comment: Very valid question! I wish to detect whenever the charger is *ready* (able) to deliver power without anything connected to it (yet).

Comment: Then the only way is by monitoring the CC1 and CC2 pins, as part of their role is essentially to advertise the availability of power.

Comment: *Monitoring the CC1 and CC2*: shall I make them common with those *blocking diodes* @Passerby mentioned, or that would ruin the charging behavior?

Comment: The blocking diodes prevent you from ruining the charging behaviour. What's important is that you don't put any significant load on the pins as that might.

Comment: I'm anyway planning to isolate these CC pins from the sensing circuit, so my idea is to use an opto-isolator. Max current I need would is around 10mA, to light up the opto-isolator's LED. Is 10mA considered *significant* in the context of CC pins?

Comment: The maximum current you can take from CC1 or CC2 is about 500uA so yes, 10mA is significant. [Take a look at how CC pins are implemented here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/574317/usb-c-and-5v-power-supply/574324)