# Convert USBC->USBA2 into USBC->Dupont connector for bread board

Tags: power-supply, usb, breadboard, usb-c

As I was tired of always lacking the right cable, I started making my own ones with the little soldering skills I have.

So now I want to convert a USBC->USBA (2.0, not blue) male-male into a USBC-> free hanging (even better,  with Dupont connectors) power cable, to be able to power my breadboard from my MacBook.

I took a random cable from my basement, and found out it was a real USBC cable (with data).

I tried to ignore this fact, but when plugging the bread board, it just does not work.

The only way I could make it work was to plug the cable into a USBC->USBA (3.0 blue) adapter, and then plugging it to my USBA3 hub and then on my Mac.

I guess doing so, I removed the need to use the white and green wires, but that's the opposite of a good solution to my cable problems.

So:

1. What should I do with the remaining white and green wires to make it work directly from my MacBook?
2. If I have a free-hanging wire at the end (like in the current config, where green and white are exposed), what would be the best way to isolate them and avoid taking the risk that they touch random things in the room...

Here below is a pic of my current wiring.

[image: Pic where I left the adapter on the cable. Of course, the plan is not to keep it]

Comment: A USB-C port doesn't output any sort of power until activated by the CC pins. Your USB-C to USB-A adaptor probably does this for you to produce 5 V.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [USB-C and >5V Power Supply](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/574317/usb-c-and-5v-power-supply)

Comment: Thanks @Finbarr, it seems like it does answer the question, except that I need a little more schematic reading skills to understand exactly which part of the cable wires corresponds to which part on the schematic. If I understand correctly, I will have to add 2 resistor on the breadboard side if I want this to work, right? or is it 4?

Comment: You'll need to figure out which wires in your cable connect to the CC pins at the plug. Failing that, buy a little USB-C power delivery module to do this for you.